# Collector Node Issue (IIB)

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

Collector node issue: I am currently using collector node to group messages (XML's). My requirement is to collect messages till the last message is received. (Reading from file input)

1. Control terminal: I'm sending a control message to stop collection and propagate to next node. But this doesn't work. As it still waits for timeout/quantity condition to be satisfied.

MY QUESTION: What condition can I use to collect messages till the last message received?

Answer (score 1):

Add a separate input terminal on the Collector node that is used to complete a collection.  Once you send a message to the second terminal, the collection is complete and propagated.

Answer (score 0):

The Control terminal can be used to signal the Collector node when complete collections are propagated, not to determine when a collection is complete.

A collection is complete when either the set number of messages are received or the timeout is exhausted for all input terminals.

So if you don't know in advance how many messages you want to include in a collection, you have 3 options:

- Set message quantity to 0 and set an appropriate timeout for input terminals.

This way the node will include all messages received within the time between the first message and the timeout value in the collection.

- Set a large number as message quantity and use collection expiry

With collection expiry, incomplete collections can be propagated to the expiry terminal, but this will work essentially the same as the previous method.

- Develop your own collector flow

You can develop a flow for combining messages using MQ Input, Get and Output nodes, keeping intermediate combined messages in MQ queues. Use this flow to combine your inputs and send the complete message onto the input queue of your processing flow.